# Font change according to different languages?

Tags: python, flask, fonts

I have an application in python flask and there are three language that i need to support and for every language i need to use different font. I am using flask-babel to change language and it is working fine. I need to change font also when language change

Comment: Please, provide some code, what you have done so far

Comment: You can [edit] your question, don't post code in comments

Comment: unable to post code in edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output some marker as to what language is being used in your templates (assuming you're using some), best use the HTML `lang` attribute:

```
<html lang="{{ the_language }}">
```

Then in your CSS stylesheet, you can assign specific fonts to specific languages:

```
:lang(en) {
    font-family: ...
}

:lang(zh) {
    font-family: ...
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang.

Answer (score 0):

Yep deceze right : but as Idrukis mentioned it's difficult to help you without codes but anyway. I think the solution is in templates themselves.

You send the language with :

return render_template(template_name.html, {'language': language})

And then you use the deceze method or an if you want to put a popup because of a language (that you don't support for example)

```
{% if language != 'en' %}
{% endif %}
```